# Assigning variables into json array data in Python

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data in the form of an array like: `[[1496832565115,13.4653],[1496835845563,13.4654]]`. I want to assign variables into it like "date" and "value". How to do that in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I added the values into a dictionary.

```
json=[[1496832565115,13.4653],[1496835845563,13.4654]]
dic={}
lis=[]
for i in range(0,len(json)):
    dic['name'+str(i)]=json[i][0]
    dic['value'+str(i)]=json[i][1]
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

if each sub array has same number of elements, for loop can be used to iterate over main array.

```
x=[[1496832565115,13.4653],[1496835845563,13.4654]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    date=x[i][0]
    value=x[i][1]
    x[i]={}
    x[i]['date']=date
    x[i]['value']=value
```